# Retrieving images in the uploaded pdf document in php

Tags: php

I am trying to display the images in the pdf document that I uploaded to the server as hyperlinks in php so that if user clicks on them they will get the corresponding document.

Please help me ,Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi,I am new to php programming and I have designed a page where user can upload the files and I am displaying them based on the name of the document ...so I don't have a idea where to start to retrieve the image content of it.

Comment: @Nathan - The PHP PDF functions have nothing to do with extracting images from existing PDF documents. While I agree that more detail might have been useful, throwing an arbitrary manual page at someone is just as bad as asking a vague question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pdfimages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html), which comes with the open-source [xpdf](http://foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) software package (for *nix operating systems). You'll have to call it through `exec` or the like, then work with the output from PHP. I am not aware of any PHP library that provides this functionality, so you're going to have to experiment.

**EDIT**

You mentioned that you aren't experienced with PHP... I thought I'd add that this isn't a quick-and-easy type of task, you certainly aren't going to find a bunch of tutorials around the internet for this.

To get started, you'll have to install the xpdf package on your server. There's a lot of different ways to do this depending on which OS you've got.

After that is set up, you'll be using a command line to execute a program on your server; you'll want to capture the output of that command in PHP and work with it further. So initially, you'll want to work out exactly what your command line will look like as well as what the output looks like and means - do this from command line, don't worry about the PHP part yet. In this case, your output is going to be a list of the image files extracted from a given PDF, you're command line call will look something like "pdfimages mypdf.pdf". Play around, find out what happens.

After you work out exactly what command line you need to send and what the command does, you can focus on the PHP angle. In a nutt shell, you want PHP to execute the exact command that you've already worked out. Look at the manual for [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for information on how to call a command line and get the output back. Write your script to make the correct call and show the call's output.

Next, move on to doing something with that output. I presume you'll want to somehow store the extracted images in a web-accessible place, put them in the database, show them to the user, etc. That is the very last stage after you've worked out the initial steps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Chris.I will try to get it.

Comment: I notice you said you're new to PHP, so I added some elaboration... you're going to learn a bit while you experiment with this!

Comment: Thanks Chris,I really appreciate your help.I tried using teh command line call and it worked fine.It listed the pdf images. I will try to work the way you said and try to get what I require.

Comment: Already got the command working, eh?  Good deal, you're halfway(ish) there! :)

Comment: Yes Chris, its working exactly how I wanted it to be :) will try to work on php now.Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks! Am I to assume you got this working to satisfaction? How'd it go?

Comment: Hello Chris,I was struggling hard to implement this in php as I am new to this concept. Can you give me any idea where I should start? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest that you start a new question with the details so I can get an idea of what you've already tried and where the failure is happening. If you want, post a link to the new question here and I can take a look, plus other SO users will have a chance to help out - if I don't know, maybe they will!

Comment: Hi Chris, Can you please let me know if there is anything wrong with the following code..if its not going to work I will create a new post as you said.

Comment: <?php
exec('pdfimages -j aaaa.pdf',$results);
 $count=count($results);
 echo $count;
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 {
  echo '<img src="'.$results[$i].'" border=0>';
 }
 
?>

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with it, BUT it does not look like it would work to display the images. Post a new question, drop the URL for it here so I am sure to see it. I am guessing that the images are not going to be in a web-accessible path, you're going to have to move the images to somewhere web accessible before you can use them in an `img` tag.